# Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property string should be of type () => string

Tags: typescript, colors

In @types/colors module, index.d.ts file contails a property bold: string. this is throwing this error:

```
node_modules/@types/colors/index.d.ts(118,9): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'bold' must be of type '() => string', but here has type 'string'.
```

I tried, replacing the property with

```
bold: () => string
```

This actually fixed the issue. However, this edit happend at node modules. As per latest release of colors module, its not there?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bold` was added in `es2015` and is defined in `lib.es2015.d.ts`, depending on what your application uses, you could use the older `lib.es5.d.ts` and maybe add back some of the `es2015` libraries, although not all will work in conjunction with `es5`. This is the configuration I tested and it works:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
        "es5",
        "es2015.iterable",
        "es2015.collection",
        "es2015.symbol.wellknown",
        "es2015.promise",
        "es2015.symbol",
        "es2015.generator",
        "dom.iterable",
        "dom",
        "scripthost"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This issue has been fixed in `colors@1.2`.

https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/168#issuecomment-371307162